# Neo4j Powershell Modules not signed

Tags: powershell, neo4j

Neo4j seems to be not signing its Powershell modules as of 3.2.2+ (Community Edition).

The following error message is received when trying to import the Neo4j Powershell module:

```
Import-Module : File D:\Apps\neo4j-community-3.2.3-windows\bin\Neo4j-Management\Neo4j-Management.psm1 cannot be loaded. The file D:\Apps\neo4j-community-3.2.3-windows\bin\Neo4j-Management\Neo4j-Management.psm1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current system.
```

I've raised an issue with neo4j (#9654) and there is another older issue (#6165) but the security protocols do not allow us to self-sign or run unrestricted.

Are there any solutions that do not require changing the security policy? Ideally, Neo4j should fix this and sign their modules

Comment: You could sign the modules yourself and assume responsibility. It is not uncommon for some entities to do this after code reviewing a specific version.